# Page Load Extremely Slow (30 minutes) After IIS Reset

Tags: 2010, performance, iis

I have seen people reporting unacceptable 90 second page load times after an IIS reset. Every time we deploy a new solution and fire an IIS reset, it takes about 30 minutes for the first page to load. I am a developer, not a server admin, so I dont know what red flags to look for in terms of farm health. What can I do to even being troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

I made also a good warmup script. He works with all supported versions 2007, 2010 and 2013.
 This script checks prerequisites for a good warmup. Try it and give me feedback !
https://spswakeup.codeplex.com/

SPSWakeUp is a PowerShell script tool to warm up all site collection in your SharePoint environment. It's compatible with all supported versions for SharePoint (2007, 2010 and 2013).

Use Internet Explorer to download JS, CSS and Pictures files, Log script results in rtf file, Email nofications, Configure automatically prerequisites for a best warm-up, possibility to add or remove custom url, setc ...

This current version supports only Windows Authentication.

For more details of available features [Click here!](https://spswakeup.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not related to SharePoint, its a general concept for IIS. When you reset IIS, all the cache and in-memory storage is gone (cleared).. When you first access the page, it builds the cache again which generally takes more time than the second attempt, which actually generates many items from Cache..

A concept called Warm-up Scripts are usually run on IIS Server, to wake it up..

There are some codeplex projects which can help you in this case:

[SPWakeUp - Wake up your Sharepoint and WSS Sites](https://spwakeup.codeplex.com/)
[PSWarmUp](http://pswarmup.codeplex.com/)

You can set any of these to run as Scheduled Task every morning (for example)..